# Content does not stay under fixed navbar nonscrolling in desktop Safari

Tags: navigation, fixed, onscroll

Have a navbar that is below my hero unit. When it is scrolled to it becomes fixed. Issue I'm having is only in desktop Safari 12.1.2 where the content is not scrolling under it. Opera, Firefox and Chrome all work fine. Site can be seen here: https://trainingmissionaviation.com

I know there's an issue with z-index and Safari, so I tried -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0); solution with no results.

css

```
.nav-wrapper {
  height:98px;
}

.logo {
  background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  float: left
}

.logo-nav {
  background-color: #ebf1f8;
  width:100%;
  height: 98px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px) {
  .hero-unit h1 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    margin: 35px 0;
  }
}

/* ---  Navigation --- */

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px
}

nav>ul, nav>ul>li, nav>ul>li>a {
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1em;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

nav>ul>li>a:link {
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1e4ba0;
}

nav>ul>li>a:link:after {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  padding: 3px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #1e4ba0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

nav>ul>li>a:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}


/ Sticky Nav
// cache the element
var $navBar = $('.logo-nav');

// find original navigation bar position
var navPos = $navBar.offset().top;

// on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {

  // get scroll position from top of the page
  var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

  // check if scroll position is >= the nav position
  if (scrollPos >= navPos) {
    $navBar.addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $navBar.removeClass('fixed');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by having the .fixed class added to .nav-wrapper instead of .logo-nav.